# C# literal int comparison versus creating a const for comparison

Tags: c#, compilation

I'm reviewing code review suggestions written from/to various developers and came across an interesting one.

Someone originally wrote a basic comparison in LINQ (EF to be specific):

```
myTable.Where(i => i.MyValue == 1);
```

Where `1` is an unchanging TypeId stored in the database.

The suggestion was to remove the hard coded value of 1 in favor of a const. So for example it would be rewritten as:

```
const int valueId = 1;
myTable.Where(i => i.MyValue == valueId);
```

From the suggestion point of view I get where they were coming from with the `const` since the code only ever needs a single copy of this value. But perhaps the compiler is smart enough to recognize that this is an unchanging value and treats it similarly.

So the question remains, does this kind of code refactor actually hold any weight other than eliminating "magic numbers"?

Comment: @dave I think `=` is not the same as `==`. In fact, quite different.

Comment: Interesting question, I usually do that, but it's like @Hosch250 said, if it represents something it should have a name. At a glance, I could see that it might be a bit easier to read as well.

Comment: @b1j I understand that you have your answer, but the question is required to stay up for the answers to have value to anyone other than you. Is there any extenuating circumstance for removing it?

Comment: Stop vandalizing your own post.  All that will accomplish is to result in a mod locking it, preventing you from editing it.

Comment: @Servy How is it that we dot not have control over our own content? The original question I asked is completely irrelevant to me after further review.

Comment: @b1j You've licenced the content under the Creative Commons by posting it to the site, giving everyone in the world the write to use, and create derived works from, that content so long as it is attributed to you.  You agreed to that licence when you posted the content to the site.  So no, you don't have the right to vandalize the content, or have it removed.

Comment: @Servy Then I will be sending a request to have this account closed. If that is the case then my contributions to this site end here.

Answer (score 2):

At this level, it is highly unlikely it matters what is produced at the compiler.  It is likely the same anyway.  The point is, what is safer for usage and easier to understand?  Does '1' represent anything in particular except the literal value '1'?  Based on the code snippet, I would guess that it does, and that is very good grounds for introducing a constant field because you now know exactly what is being checked against here.

Is this literal value '1' used in any other places that would need to be changed if the value change, for example, to '2'?  If so, that also is very good grounds for introducing a constant field because now you only have to change the value in a single place, rather than search your entire code base, and most likely missing at least one instance.

Also, credit to Ixrec from Programmers, `valueId` is a terrible name for a constant as it does not say what the value is.  A better name would be `answersId`, if, for example, the '1' represented answers while '0' represented questions and '2' represented comments.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, both versions of the code will compile to exactly the same IL.

A constant is not a variable. Any usage of a constant is replaced at compile-time by it's value.

There are 2 advantages of using a `const` instead of a literal

1. The constant can be defined once and used in many places. So if you ever need to change the value of the constant, you only need to change it in one place*
2. You can give a meaningful name to the constant.

(*) Never change value of a `public const` field - all other assemblies using this constant will have to be recompiled to use the updated value.

Comment: I want to stress out the 2nd point. It makes code more clean. Having number alone is what some call Magic Numbers. http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceMagicNumberWithSymbolicConstant.html